# Neural Network Input and Output Data formatting

Tags: input, normalization, scaling, radial

and thanks for reading my thread.

I have read some of the previous posts on formatting/normalising input data for a Neural Network, but cannot find something that addresses my queries specifically.  I apologise for the long post.

I am attempting to build a radial basis function network for analysing horse racing data.  I realise that this has been done before, but the data that I have is "special" and I have a keen interest in racing/sportsbetting/programming so would like to give it a shot!

Whilst I think I understand the principles for the RBFN itself, I am having some trouble understanding the normalisation/formatting/scaling of the input data so that it is presented in a "sensible manner" for the network, and I am not sure how I should formulate the output target values.

For example, in my data I look at the "Class change", which compares the class of race that the horse is running in now compared to the race before, and can have a value between -5 and +5.  I expect that I need to rescale these to between -1 and +1 (right?!), but I have noticed that many more runners have a class change of 1, 0 or -1 than any other value, so I am worried about "over-representation".  It is not possible to gather more data for the higher/lower class changes because thats just 'the way the data comes'.  Would it be best to use the data as-is after scaling, or should I trim extreme values, or something else?

Similarly, there are "continuous" inputs - like the "Days Since Last Run".  It can have a value between 1 and about 1000, but values in the range of 10-40 vastly dominate.  I was going to scale these values to be between 0 and 1, but even if I trim the most extreme values before scaling, I am still going to have a huge representation of a certain range - is this going to cause me an issue?  How are problems like this usually dealt with?

Finally, I am having trouble understanding how to present the "target" values for training to the network.  My existing results data has the "win/lose" (0 or 1?) and the odds at which the runner won or lost.  If I just use the "win/lose", it treats all wins and loses the same when really they're not - I would be quite happy with a network that ignored all the small winners but was highly profitable from picking 10-1 shots.  Similarly, a network could be forgiven for "losing" on a 20-1 shot but losing a bet at 2/5 would be a bad loss.  I considered making the results (+1 * odds) for a winner and (-1 / odds) for a loser to capture the issue above, but this will mean that my results are not a continuous function as there will be a "discontinuity" between short price winners and short price losers.

Should I have two outputs to cover this - one for bet/no bet, and another for "stake"?

I am sorry for the flood of questions and the long post, but this would really help me set off on the right track.

Thank you for any help anyone can offer me!

Kind regards,

Paul

Answer (score 1):

The documentation that came with your RBFN is a good starting point to answer some of these questions.
Trimming data aka "clamping" or "winsorizing" is something I use for similar data. For example "days since last run" for a horse could be anything from just one day to several years but tends to centre in the region of 20 to 30 days. Some experts use a figure of say 63 days to indicate a "spell" so you could have an indicator variable like "> 63 =1 else 0" for example. One clue is to look at outliers say the upper or lower 5% of any variable and clamp these.
If you use odds/dividends anywhere make sure you use the probabilities ie 1/(odds+1) and a useful idea is to normalize these to 100%.
The odds or parimutual prices tend to swamp other predictors so one technique is to develop separate models, one for the market variables (the market model) and another for the non-market variables (often called the "fundamental" model).